# Get Specific Attributes of all Array Keys in PHP Foreach Loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, simplexml

I'm working with a multi-dimensional PHP array that is converted from an XML file, and am struggling to grab specific attributes from all key names (I don't know the name of all keys, but they all have the same attributes.)

Each Key inside "$player_stats" is structured like this in the array:

```
[RandomKeyName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [assists] => 0.10
                [rebounds] => 8
                [operator] => >
                [overall] => 1.45
            )

    )
```

I'm trying to achieve something like below. Am I not able to grab attributes from keys when using $key => $value?

```
foreach ($player_stats as $key => $value) {

    $rebounds = $key->rebounds;
    $assists = $key->assists;

    echo "$key has $rebounds Rebounds and $assists Assists. <br>";
}
```

$key works in this example but the attributes I tried grabbing don't. Any tips or pointers for grabbing specific attributes for all keys without knowing the key names would be great, thanks!

edit:

The part of the XML I'm trying to get key objects of:

```
<Player_Stats>
  <RandomKeyName1 assists="0.04" rebounds="9" operator="&gt;" overall="0.78" />
  <RandomKeyName2 assists="0.04" rebounds="4" operator="&gt;" overall="2.07" />
  <RandomKeyName3 assists="0.04" rebounds="1" operator="&gt;" overall="3.76" />
  <RandomKeyName4 assists="0.04" rebounds="10" operator="&gt;" overall="0.06" />
</Player_Stats>
```

Comment: The keys don't actually have values in the XML file, they just have added attributes which is what I'm after. So $value is empty. foreach $key => $value is just the only way I know how to access all the keys without knowing their actual names :/

Comment: Since the PHP array is more than one level deep, maybe you are not going deep enough?

Comment: It is deep enough because when I do echo "$key <br>"; in the loop, it does list out all of the keys

Comment: Any chance you can demonstrate the look of the XML?

Comment: updated with XML structure I'm working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, $value is a SimpleXMLElement object. You could get the attributes using [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), which you can iterate across with another foreach.

Which would look like this (though I haven't tested this myself).

```
foreach ($player_stats as $xmlKey => $xmlElement) {

    foreach ($xmlElement->attributes() as $attrKey => $value) {

        if ($attrKey === 'rebounds')
            $rebounds = $value;

        if ($attrKey === 'assists')
            $assists = $value;

    }
    echo "$xmlKey has $rebounds Rebounds and $assists Assists. <br>";
}
```

Comment: This actually worked without any adjustments. Perfect! Now I have a much better understanding of what I should've been doing. Thanks!